# Convert space separated list into coma separated list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have pandas dataframe where the row is `[“a” “b”]`. how I can convert it into the comma separated list like `[“a”, “b”]`?

I’m expecting to get back list with two comma separated elements

Comment: What's the output `df.head(5).to_dict()`?

Comment: Where are you reading that dataFrame from, Can you give any sample data?

Comment: "Space separated list" and "comma separated list" aren't things in Python. All lists are displayed with comma separators. Is the input actually a string? Also, the output you're showing has curly quotes, which aren't valid in Python. Please [edit] to clarify. See [mre] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

If your column contains string like `["a" "b"]`, you can use `str.findall` to convert them as real list or `str.replace` to replace `' '` by `', '`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['["a" "b"]']})

df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.findall(r'"([^"]+)"')

df['col3'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'"(\s+)"', '", "', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        col1        col3    col2
0  ["a" "b"]  ["a", "b"]  [a, b]
```